# Why libc contains synonyms?

Tags: libc, synonym

> synonyms of the form _name exist for name entries that are not listed
>   with a leading underscore prepended to their name. Thus libc contains
>   both getopt and _getopt, for example.

```
Figure 3-2: libc Contents, Names with Synonyms

  __assert     getdate      lockf **     sleep        tell ** 
  cfgetispeed  getopt       lsearch      strdup       tempnam
  cfgetospeed  getpass      memccpy      swab         tfind
  cfsetispeed  getsubopt    mkfifo       tcdrain      toascii
  cfsetospeed  getw         mktemp       tcflow       _tolower
  ctermid      hcreate      monitor      tcflush      tsearch
  cuserid      hdestroy     nftw         tcgetattr    _toupper
  dup2         hsearch      nl_langinfo  tcgetpgrp    twalk
  fdopen       isascii      pclose       tcgetsid     tzset
  __filbuf     isatty       popen        tcsendbreak  _xftw
  fileno       isnan        putenv       tcsetattr    
  __flsbuf     isnand **    putw         tcsetpgrp    
  fmtmsg **    lfind        setlabel     tdelete
```

Why libc contains synonyms?

**UPDATE**

How to use the synonyms ? I tried replace `getopt` with `_getopt` but only to get `undefined reference to`_getopt'`

Answer (score 0):

Probably because they were originally non-standard, and later added to POSIX, removed the prefixes, but required backwards compatibility, and were kept, thus naturally synonyms were needed.

Comment: @Je Rog: I think they'd be available anywhere the "normal" name is. Check the headers to be sure, but I would think simple `#defines` are used.

Comment: The synonyms DO exist in libc and that has nothing to do with macros/preprocessors.

Answer (score 0):

Or possibly (to follow on @rubenvb's answer, which I think is correct) to maintain source-level compatibility with some of the Win32 library functions that are so named. _toupper is one of these.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from "SYSTEM V APPLICATION BINARY INTERFACE,"

> the C library includes synonyms for some of its services. These other symbols are available to conform to language and system standards. As an example, System V deﬁnes `read` as the name of an operating system facility. On the other hand, ANSI C does not deﬁne `read`, and it prohibits a strictly conforming implementation from usurping application names without a leading underscore (_). Thus if a synonym for `read` were not available, the system could not support a strictly conforming implementation of the ANSI C language.
>
> NOTE: Although synonyms are not required for the following interfaces, they are permitted to exist.

In short, synonyms are for conformance with ANSI C recommendation. If you use Linux, some of functions with synonyms in ELF format document do not seem to have synonyms in `glibc`, so you might want to check the existence of symbol with `readelf -s /usr/lib/libc.a`.